# como pré-visualizar ficheiro .md durante edição?

Tags: wysiwyg, markdown

Gostaria de criar documentação em markdown para uma biblioteca no github. No entanto como não tenho forma de pré-visualizar o que estou a fazer, é comum fazer erros que apenas são descobertos quando o ficheiro já está publicado.
Existem algumas ferramentas onde seja possível observar em tempo real as edições que estou a fazer em ficheiros .md?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazê-lo de forma online através deste [site](http://dillinger.io/) ou então utilizar um dos pacotes que já vem por defeito com o [atom](https://atom.io/), chamado de [markdown-preview](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-preview).
Para ter acesso à visualização do que está a ser editado basta estar com a aba selecionada, de um dos seguintes tipos de ficheiros:

- .markdown
- .md
- .mdown
- .mkd
- .mkdown
- .ron
- .txt

E no menu principal do atom selecionar o seguinte:

1. Packages
2. Markdown Preview
3. Toggle Preview

Ou então simplesmente pressionar ao mesmo tempo:

```
ctrl-shift-m
```

Um exempo pode ser visto aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Existe também um [plugin para o Google Chrome chamado MarkViewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markview/iaddkimmopgchbbnmfmdcophmlnghkim), muito bom  e simples. Basta abrir o arquivo no navegador (com o plugin instalado) que ele já reconhece e formata. Não é necessário ficar atualizando a página a cada alteração do arquivo, o navegador já detecta as alterações e atualiza automaticamente.

Site do plugin: http://www.baiyunconsulting.com/portfolio-markview.html